# get Equation from Table of values

Tags: calculus, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I'm trying to get an equation to represent this table of values. I've been trying for hours and I can't get something that is accurate. There must be something I am missing when it comes to solving this?  closest I could get was x = 40.5y^2 + 175.5y + 100

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 100 |
| 1 | 255 |
| 2 | 475 |
| 3 | 770 |
| 4 | 1150 |
| 5 | 1635 |
| 6 | 2235 |
| 7 | 2960 |
| 8 | 3820 |
| 9 | 4825 |
| 10 | 5985 |

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Are you sure that's the goal of the problem? I don't really see that as a legitimate calculus or matrix homework question (am professor, 20+ years). I could see it being about finding a *line of best fit* which is not a solution but an approximation.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I wish it was a homework question. No its actually for a bot I am scripting for a personal project. I need to to be able to use y to calculate x. but this math is beyond me, and it doesnt need  to be accurate, like as long as the answer rounds out to to the desired out

Comment: OK, then maybe read up on [Polynomial Interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation). But first be sure that's really what you need, or if a line of best fit is good enough.